# Differentiate the cucmber step definition based on argument type

Tags: java, spring, cucumber

I have two cucumber step definition like as shown below

```
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
:
:
@And("^(.+) has a value (false|true)$")
public void addValues(String key, Boolean value) {
    values.put(key, value);
}

@And("^(.+) has a value (.+)$")
public void addValues(String key, String value) {
    values.put(key, value);
}
```

In the first step definition I want to set the value as **boolean** and in the second definition the value as **String** but some how I'm getting `io.cucumber.core.runner.AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException`

for the given statements

```
Given name has a value Manu
And isMajor has a value true
:
:
```

Can someone please tell me how to differentiate the step definition with the same statement but with different argument type

My cucumber version is 6.8.1

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```regex
^(.+) has a value (.+)$
```

to this:

```regex
^(.+) has a value ((?!true|false).+)$
```

This will eliminate ambiguity.

**P.S.** - After the change you entire class would look like:

```java
public class ClassicStepDefs {

    Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();

    @And("^(.+) has a value ((?!true|false).+)$")
    public void addValues(String key, String value) {
        values.put(key, value);
    }

    @And("^(.+) has a value (false|true)$")
    public void addValues(String key, Boolean value) {
        values.put(key, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: This did'nt work

Comment: What do you mean? I tested your example. What's the outcome?

Comment: I tried that, still I'm getting the same exception, is it because of the version

Comment: `isMajor has a value true` is still navigating to `^(.+) has a value (.+)$` and not `^(.+) has a value ((?!true|false).+)$`

Comment: If you followed my advice accurately you would not have `^(.+) has a value (.+)$` any more. Hence you couldn't be navigated to that. The change you need to perform is `^(.+) has a value (.+)$` ---> `^(.+) has a value ((?!true|false).+)$`

Comment: @AlexMan I added the whole picture to my answer

Answer (score 0):

The step `isMajor has a value true` matches both regular expressions. So Cucumber can't figure out which method to call. If you make the other regular expression match any argument except `true/false` your step definitions are no longer ambiguous.

You can probably do that with a negative lookahead but I'll leave that as exercise for some one else.